# Cocoalumberjack check version

Tags: ios, logging, cocoalumberjack

I imported CocoaLumberjack source files into my app a few months ago, and wondering if I need to update the source. I'm not sure how to check what version I'm running so I can compare against the latest source files. How do I check? There doesn't seem to be a 'version number' call in any of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the version of CocoaPods framework at Podfile.lock, if you used CocoaPods to install Cocoalumberjack.